# How to return ID of existing row if there is a duplicate row during MySQL INSERT?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables: `movies` and `genres`, and a junction table `movieOfGenre` for many-to-many relationships between the `movies` and `genres` tables. Now, when I am using transactions to insert movies and genres into my database using PHP, genres were being created twice even if there was a duplicate. Then I updated the code with `...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...` and now if there is an existing genre with the same name, the auto_increment ID of the existing genre is being updated when I use this transaction query:

```
mysqli_autocommit($connect, false);
$query_success = true;
$stmt = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO movies (id, title, plot, rating, releaseDate, duration, language, country, posterUrl, trailerUrl) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssssss", $defaultId, $title, $plot, $rating, $releaseDate, $duration, $language, $country, $poster, $trailer);
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    $query_success = false;
}
$movieId = mysqli_insert_id($connect);
$stmt->close();

foreach ($genres as $genre) {
    $stmt = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO genres (id, name) VALUES (?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = LAST_INSERT_ID()");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $defaultId, $genre);
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        $query_success = false;
    }
    $genreId = mysqli_insert_id($connect);
    $stmt->close();

    $stmt = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO movieofgenre (movieId, genreId) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $movieId, $genreId);
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        $query_success = false;
    }
    $stmt->close();
}

if ($query_success) { 
    mysqli_commit($connect);
} else { ?>
    alert('Error adding movie.');
    <?php mysqli_rollback($connect);
}
```

How do I write the query so that if during insertion there is an existing row with the same `genre.name`, it returns the ID of the existing row without updating it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot get that value directly from the insert. But you can simply query it (run another `select` after you inserted it instead of querying for mysqli_insert_id). Btw, it is a bad idea to update the id (e.g. because all entries in `movieofgenre` for that genre will become useless or have to be updated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `genres.name` should be a unique column:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE genres
   ...
   UNIQUE KEY name
   ```
2. use `IGNORE` - duplicate exception will not be thrown

   ```
   INSERT IGNORE INTO genres (name) VALUES (?)
   ```
3. get the id by name:

   ```
   SELECT id FROM genres WHERE name = ?
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this help but you may want to check example below.  Lazy to do php coding this days, But I have similar issue with MYSQL last time if I understand your issue correctly  :P

```
INSERT INTO sample_table (unique_id, code) VALUES ('$unique_id', '$code')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE code= '$code'
```

Hope this resolve your problem